# Laravel “CSRF token mismatch” for POST with laravel-cors and axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, csrf

I have a domain_A running **Laravel 5.8**  engine to return API on *web route*. It must check origins to let serve just a few domains, included domain_B.

**Barryvdh/laravel-cors**
I installed [barryvdh/laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) by composer and configured it globally updating the Kernel.php. This should works on web route too.

**kernel.php**

```
protected $middleware = [
   ...
  \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
];
```

Then I config the **Laravel Cors** using the standard configuration as test to allow any domain.

**/config/cors.php**

```
 return [
    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['http:www.domain_b.com','https:www.domain_b.com','http:domain_b.com'],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'X-CSRF-TOKEN', 'Content-Type', 'X-Requested-With'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'], // ex: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT',  'DELETE']
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
];
```

The axios config is:

**(domain_a)/ Repository.js**

```
import axios from 'axios/index';

const baseDomain = "https://domain_a";
const baseURL = `${baseDomain}`;

let withCredentials = false;

const token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

const headers = {
   'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token.content,
   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
   'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
};


export default axios.create({
    baseURL,
    withCredentials: withCredentials,
    headers: headers
});
```

GET requests are filtered as well, PUT request return a 419 error why? I have set 'allowedMethods' => ['*'] so it should work...  what I'm missing?

[**EDIT**]

ON debug I got this error right now...

> message: "CSRF token mismatch."

Why POST doesn't get the header Token?

I tried to pass the POST token also like this:

```
 const token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
const options = {
    headers: {
        'Authorization' :  'bearer '+token.content,
    }
};
const body = {};
return Repository.post(`${resource}/${$playerId}/${$cozzaloID}`, body, options)
```

**Preflight Header Response**

```
 Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization, content-type, x-requested-with, x-csrf-token
 Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.******.**
 Cache-Control: no-cache, private
 Connection: Keep-Alive
 Content-Length: 0
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
 Date: Mon, 01 Jul 2019 05:14:22 GMT
 Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
 Server: Apache
 X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.30, PleskLin
```

**Header Response**:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.xxxxxxx.xx
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 01 Jul 2019 05:14:22 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=97
Server: Apache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin,Authorization
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.30, PleskLin
```

**Header Request**:

```
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: Bearer jW6pFcVlkKyApCxtZIlfaHDPMSFWCWcbnPPTQ7EJ
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://www.xxxxxxx.xx 
Referer: http://www.xxxxxx.xx/players/739
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 
Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-TOKEN: jW6pFcVlkKyApCxtZIlfaHDPMSFWCWcbnPPTQ7EJ
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

*Note about **token***: It should be OK because it is the same as another GET request done in the same task.

Comment: You don’t need to put Access-Control-Allow-Origin into the allowedHeaders value.

Comment: Tanks. Removed both on client and server side: GET it's working and POST continue to NOT working for a bad token passed

Comment: Have you tried `'Bearer '+token.content`? That is, uppercase, instead of `bearer`. I don’t know whether it’s case-sensitive or not…

Comment: It should work with and without any capital letters. But not in my case :(

Comment: Have you tried debugging to ensure that your `document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')` is actually getting what you expect? And that `token.content` is?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you but I can't figure it. I have edited my question with  header request/response

Comment: does `(domain_a)/Repository.js` above mean you are running the script from `domain_a` instead of `domain_b`?

Comment: @YohanesGultom I have 2 (sub)domains: www.domain.com (A) and  api.domain.com (B)

Comment: @YohanesGultom Repository.js is on the forntend side (www by VUE), and config/cors.php is on backend side (api by Laravel)

Comment: On the backend of the server you’re sending the request to, have you checked to see what token it’s actually expected? Maybe the server logs show that — *“expected token XXX but received token YYY”* or whatever. If not, maybe you can add some debugging on the server side to print out the expected token value to the logs or wherever, and you can examine that.

Comment: The answers at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43845050/441757 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/36615149/441757 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/38764345/441757 suggest that you might be able to resolve this by clearing your session storage files with `rm -f {your_web_app}/storage/framework/sessions/*` or such.

Comment: Try passing the CSRF token in `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header (not in `Authorization`) https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: @sideshowbarker nope...  sorry it doesn't fix it. But I got solution! It was in web router back to api router.

Comment: @YohanesGultom, thanks for the help but it doesn't fix... I got solution restoring the web route using API route. I wrote about this in the first lines of my post... I really appreciate your help guys! TAHNKS!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use routes/api.php for apis routing,
don't use the routes/web.php for api.

If you want to use sub-domain then do required changes in following file:

> app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php

Original:

```
protected function mapApiRoutes() {
    Route::prefix('api')
    ->middleware('api')
    ->namespace($this->namespace)
    ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

Updated:

```
protected function mapApiRoutes() {
    Route::domain('api.' .  env('APP_URL'))
    ->middleware('api')
    ->namespace($this->namespace)
    ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for writing, Milan! I prefer to use a dedicated subdomain (api.domain.com) instead of www.domain.com/api. For this reason, I'm using the web route. Do you think this is not correct? Why?

Comment: Wow! Thanks to @Milan, I think to have fixed my issue!!!  I had to change the ENV var APP_URO from APP_URL=https://api.domain.org to APP_URL=domain.org is it ok? Or it could have a bad effect?

Comment: In your case you must need to set APP_URL to main domain. This is the right way don't fear for that.

Comment: I'm getting an issue sending the recover password link, because of this I receive link having a double domain: https://api.domain.org/domain.org/password/reset/xxxx . Can you help me to fix it? Thanks!!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57073662/laravel-wrong-domain-in-reset-password-link

Answer (score 0):

in the address

vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php

comment this

```
        // Check if we're dealing with CORS and if we should handle it
         if (! $this->shouldRun($request)) {
         return $next($request);
          }
```